# Having Two QThreadPool in an Application

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a ShortTask and a LongTask. I dont want threads that running LongTask affect execution speed of threads that running ShortTash. My PC has 8 threads, if I create 2 threadpools each with 4 max num of threads, will those threads become isolated from each other automatically?

```
QThreadPool* shortPool = new QThreadPool(this);
shortPool->setMaxThreadCount(QThread::idealThreadCount() / 2);
QThreadPool* longPool = new QThreadPool(this);
longPool->setMaxThreadCount(QThread::idealThreadCount() / 2);
```

Comment: Not completely, no.  Main memory access contention may require occasional extra wait-states.  Not much to worry about in most cases.

Comment: Anyway, why not just create one pool with eight threads?

Comment: If you want to prioritize one task over another then try making use of the [`priority`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#start-1) parameter in `QThreadPool::start`.  Although the documentation is somewhat vague.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for response. the ShortTasks are handling a real time task that can not be delayed. also threads handling LongTask must finish in less than 1 sec. If the LongTasks don't finish in 1 sec new data to process arrive and after a while new pieces of data get staked in memory app crashes.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for response. As I explained the situation more in the above comment, If I define ShortTask with higher priority and since ShortTask executes much more frequent in application, then LongTask get delayed more and I also have no control over its delay.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comments.  You state that the ShortTask is realtime but that LongTask *must* complete within one second.  That suggests LongTask is the one with 'hard' realtime constraints.  You also seem to suggest that a new LongTask can't be started before the existing one has completed.  Without more information regarding the precise nature of the tasks this appears to be an xy-problem.

Comment: @G.M. thanks for response. The ShortTask do a light computation on data stream and after that LongTask process the result of shortTask. shortTask input is a big amount of data but LongTask takes longer to process. I hope it clarifies